# spfx MSGraphClient

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I need to write a webpart, which shows data from the MS Graph.

I wrote this example code

```
    import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
    import {
      BaseClientSideWebPart,
      IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
      PropertyPaneTextField
    } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
    import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

    import styles from './HelloWorldWebPart.module.scss';
    import * as strings from 'HelloWorldWebPartStrings';

    export interface IHelloWorldWebPartProps {
      description: string;
    }

    export default class HelloWorldWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloWorldWebPartProps> {

      public render(): void {

          const client: MSGraphClient = this.context.serviceScope.consume(MSGraphClient.serviceKey);
          // get information about the current user from the Microsoft Graph
          client
            .api('/me/?$select=displayName,department')
            .get((error, user: MicrosoftGraph.User, rawResponse?: any) => {

              // Resulat like
              //  {
              //    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(displayName,department)/$entity",
              //    "department": "Finance",
              //    "displayName": "Megan Bowen"
              //  }

            });
          }

        this.domElement.innerHTML = `
          <div class="${ styles.helloWorld }"
                  <span class="${ styles.title }">Welcome to SharePoint!</span>

                  <span> Name</span>
                  <span> Deartment</span>

          </div>`;
      }

      protected get dataVersion(): Version {
        return Version.parse('1.0');
      }

      protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
        return {
          pages: [
            {
              header: {
                description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
              },
              groups: [
                {
                  groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
                  groupFields: [
                    PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                      label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                    })
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        };
      }
    }
```

But wow I can bring the Department and Name (result form the MS Graph) into the HTML rendering?

When I really understand the MSGraphClient works asynchron. How can I get save, that first the MSGraphClient gets the result and the build the HTLM rendering part?

Thanks for your help
Stefan

Comment: do you want to use a JS framework like React in your webpart ?

Comment: No, I like to use no JS framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the BaseClientSideWebPart class, you'll find a method you can override `protected onInit(): Promise<void>;` in you own webpart definition.
it should look like that:

```
protected async onInit(): Promise<void> {
await super.onInit();
// your code to get your data and affect it to a property of the class
}
```

The great thing with the onInit method is that it will execute before rendering your webpart, and display a spinner to the user as long as it's not loaded.
Then in your render method you can simply read the data from the property of your class you affected earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiair yet with javascript async, then it would be good to read more about: [Await](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/call-microsoft-graph-using-graphhttpclient) and [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

That said, there's a tutorial on using the graph in a SPFx project: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/call-microsoft-graph-using-graphhttpclient

And there's also a SharePoint PnP starter kit with lots of samples and best practices: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-starter-kit. Although these can become quite complex and use React.